# Вывод в одну строку из разных print в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, print

Мне нужно сделать так, что бы функция `print()`, написаная таким вот обрзом:

```
print('a')
print('b')
print('c')
```

выводила что то такое:

```
> C:\Users\User\Documents> python test.py
abc
```

Выводиться должно в одной строке, но `print()` в коде в разных строках!
Буду очень рад, если кто-нибуть поможет.

Comment: А собрать то что должно выводиться в одну строку и одним принтом вывести не вариант?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Функция `print()` имеет такие ключевые параметры:

- `sep=` – когда выводится более значений, каким символом или строкой их отделить
  (стандартно пробелом, т.е. строкой `' '`),
- `end=` – какой символ или строка выводить после вывода (всех) значений
  (стандартно переходом на новую строку, т.е. строкой `'\n'`),
- `file=` – в какой файл выводить значения
  (стандартно на экран, т.е.  `sys.stdout`),
- `flush=` – если поток (сохранен в буфере) немедленно вывести в файл
  (стандартно «нет», т.е. `False`).

В вашем случае хотите после вывода значения *остаться в той же строке*, значит, вы не хотите стандартного окончания переходом на новую строку (`end='\n'`), но окончить чем-то другим (пробелом, запятой, и тд.) тоже нет.

Потому окончите вывод *пустой строкой* (`''`):

```
print('a', end='')
print('b', end='')
print('c')
```

Comment: Благодарю за столь понятный и развернутый ответ

Comment: @V-MazOriginal, не стоит.

Answer (score 3):

Самый обычный способ:

```py
print('a' + 'b' + 'c')
```

Comment: Как вы поняли  в вопросе эту фразу: _но print() в коде в разных строках!_ (завершает фразу восклицательный знак)?

Comment: Так как заказчик не хотел этот вариант (Я понимаю что так можно было сделать и предлогал), пришлось изгаляться так как, цытирую: "Красота кода в данном случае для меня важна, по этому сделайте так!"