# Как сделать так, чтобы символы выводились принтом в одной строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def map(a):
    for i in range(a):
        print("_")
map(10)
```

Вот что я пытался сделать. Символы выводятся каждый на новой строке, а мне нужно чтобы они выводились на одной строке по очереди.

P.S [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1240831/525500) уже было рассказано о всех возможностях функции '''print'''

Comment: Лучше не перекрывать встроенные функции питона, в данном случае `map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать `print()` с параметром `end=""`.

```py
def map(a):
    for i in range(a):
        print("_", end="")  # или " ", если необходимо.
map(10)
```

Другой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1240831/418625) где более подробно рассказано о всех возможностях `print`