# как полученные буквы вывести в одну строку python

Tags: python

```
pop = input()
len(pop)
a = len(pop)
i = 2
for i in range (a):
    if i % 2== 0:
      print (pop[2 + i] )
      end = ''
      i = i + 2
print(str(i))
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод в одну строку из разных print в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240814/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-print-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 2):

Все гораздо проще, в одну строку:

```
pop = input()
print(pop[1::2])
```

Результат:
вводим:

```
Popolam
```

получаем:

```
ooa
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pop = input()
a = len(pop)
end=""
for i in range (0,a):
    if (i+1)%2== 0:
      end += pop[i]
print(end)
```

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно каждую 2 буквы вывести отдельно?

Comment: нет,надо каждую 2 букву вывести вместе с остальными

Comment: Popolam->ooa вот такой должен быть ответ

Comment: Взяли каждую вторую букву и вывели её в конце отдельно... всё

Comment: Или нужно половину слова отрезать?)

Comment: а как взять каждую 2 букву и склеить их в отдельное слово?

Comment: поправил код.
Для этого вам нужно брать её id +1 (так как id начинается с 0) и таким образом мы получим её порядковый номер и делить её на 2. Далее прибавляем букву к переменной END и потом выводим её один раз\

Comment: Надо будет попробовать

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает как надо!

Comment: Зачем так сложно???? Это же элементарная задача. Но один оператор! Какой цикл? Зачем???